# Align in RichtextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Using this:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText("EMPID: " + "\t\t" + "4001");
richTextBox1.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine);
richTextBox1.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine);
richTextBox1.AppendText("EmployeeName: " + "\t\t" + "Taborjakol");
```

I got this:

[image]

How I will perfectly Align it to this:

[image]

Comment: I suggest use a gridview ..

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you use a fixed-width font like `Courier New`

Comment: Remove one \t in the last line and add a |

Comment: @ Arun: The | is actual the blinking cursor that got into the screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is change the tab positions of the RichTextBoxControl.

```
richTextBox1.SelectionTabs = new int[] { 90, 180, 270, 360 };

richTextBox1.AppendText("EMPID: " + "\t\t" + "4001");
richTextBox1.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine);
richTextBox1.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine);
richTextBox1.AppendText("EmployeeName: " + "\t\t" + "Taborjakol");
```

The SelectionsTab property re-defines the spaces that are used for each tab in the RichTextBox control. You need to experiment with the tab settings to get the best result for your text.

Comment: Note: in FW 4.8 in 2022 this SelectionTabs property still does NOT work, whatever font I choose ! For a listbox it can be done, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869948/how-to-format-alignment-in-listbox

Answer (score 1):

Replace your last line of code with

```
richTextBox1.AppendText("EmployeeName: " + "\t" + "Taborjakol");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have to use a richtextbox, you should definetly have a look at the gridview or if you use third party tools like Telerik, DevCraft, ComponentOne and others most of them will have a control called Property Grid that has a layout you might be interested in.

If there is no other way around in using a richtextbox, you have to do the following:

1. Get a fixed-width font or called monospaced font http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font
2. Evalute the amout of characters which share the same width as a tab (I dont know the number of character have to figure it out yourself with testing)
3. Get the max length of your text at the left side (your "columnnames" I guess - like "EmployeeName")
4. Do some math - max length + one tab = x characters
5. now fill the remaining text at your left side with the neccessary tabs (can be anything from 1 to x) to get the same amout of characters as calculated in 4.

But again a richtextbox isnt the ideal control for this kind of scenario.

**Edit:**

Here some Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int FetchTestData = 50;
    private const int TabCharLength = 5;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //With this Fontsettings - 5 chars = 1 Tab - this changes with different fonts
        this.richTextBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

        var type = typeof(TestData);
        var list = GetTestData();
        var maxProperty = GetMaxProperty(type);
        maxProperty = FillToNext(maxProperty);
        var properties = GetProperties(type);

        for (var i = 0; i < FetchTestData; i++)
        {
            var data = list[i];

            foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(propertyInfo.Name);

                var tabs = GetNumberOfTabs(maxProperty, propertyInfo.Name.Length);
                for (var j = 0; j < tabs; j++)
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("\t");

                richTextBox1.AppendText(Convert.ToString(propertyInfo.GetValue(data)));

                richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            }

            if (i >= FetchTestData - 1) 
                continue;

            richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            richTextBox1.AppendText("---------- NEXT DATA ----------");
            richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

    private int GetNumberOfTabs(int maxLength, int textLength)
    {
        if ((maxLength % TabCharLength) != 0)
            maxLength = FillToNext(maxLength);

        var difLength = maxLength - textLength;

        return (int)(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(difLength / TabCharLength)) + 1);
    }

    private int FillToNext(int maxLength)
    {
        return maxLength + (5 - (maxLength % TabCharLength));
    }

    private PropertyInfo[] GetProperties(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

        return type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }

    private int GetMaxProperty(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

        return (from x in GetProperties(type)
                select x.Name.Length).Max();
    }

    private List<TestData> GetTestData()
    {
        var returnValue = new List<TestData>();

        for (int i = 0; i < FetchTestData; i++)
        {
            returnValue.Add(new TestData()
            {
                ID = i,
                Name = "NameValue " + i,
                Description = "DescriptionValue " + i,
                PropertyA = "PropertyAValue " + i,
                PropertyB = "PropertyBValue " + i,
                SomeReallyLongPropertyName = "RandomStuff... " + i
            });
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}

public class TestData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    public string SomeReallyLongPropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated you firstly would want to set the font to a mono-space font, this means that each letter will be the same size.

So you will see something like this:

> EEEEEEEEEEE

Rather than

> EeEeeiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii

Secondly, you could align the text which may improve it slightly:

```
richTextBox1.SelectAll();
richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

However unless you have to, I would suggest using a different control:

- Gridview
- Listbox

These are both easy to format, gridview has tabs, and the listbox you can use string.Format when entering the values.