# How to format alignment in ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

I add values to a ListBox,

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
     lbBeamValue.Items.Add("Beam " + i.ToString() + " : " + value1[i] + " Angle " + i.ToString() + " : " + value2[i]);
}
```

which is displayed something like:

```
Beam 0: 0.12 Angle 0: 0.65
Beam 1: 10.113213 Angle 1: 0.23
```

Is there a way to ensure that the `Angle` aligns in every row? Like:

```
Beam 0: 0.12      Angle 0: 0.65
Beam 1: 10.113213 Angle 1: 0.23
```

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No simple control will allow you the use of tabs; so you either need a control, like `ListView` that has columns or you need to chose a fixe-sized font (like `Consolas`) and pad each item to a given length with `string.PadLeft` and `string.PadRight`:

```
lbBeamValue.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8f);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    listBox2.Items.Add("Beam " + (i).ToString("#0").PadLeft(2) + " : " + 
          value1[i].ToString().PadRight(11) + " Angle " + i.ToString() + " : " + 
          value2[i]);
        };
```

Note the `String.Format` also allows you to build a complex string with padding.

[image]

Comment: I would avoid the use PadRight(11) for a problem like this. It is not always appropriate to add a PadRight for every string and to do this neatly, you'll have to set that length according to context.. the value of 11 cannot be used for any string and, as you note it requires a non-proportional system font. See Bob Moore's solution with SetListTabs(), that works with any font.

Answer (score 2):

Why not rather make use of a [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents a Windows list view control, which displays a collection of
>   items that can be displayed using one of four different views.

There you can specify the [View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columns(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A listbox will still allow the use of tabs. You can achieve it like this:

```
  public Form1 ()
  {
     InitializeComponent ();
     // ....

     int [] MyTabs = {20,70,130};
     SetListTabs (lbMessages, MyTabs);
  }

  private void btnAddTabbed_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     lbMessages.Items.Add ("1\t2\t3\t4");
     lbMessages.Items.Add ("40\t50\t60\t70");
     lbMessages.Items.Add ("100\t200\t300\t400");
  }

  private void SetListTabs (ListBox lb, IEnumerable<int> newTabs)
  {
     lb.UseCustomTabOffsets = true;

     ListBox.IntegerCollection lbTabs = lb.CustomTabOffsets;
     lbTabs.Clear ();

     foreach (int tab in newTabs)
     {
        lbTabs.Add (tab);
     }
  }

  private void btnAddTabbed_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     lbMessages.Items.Add ("1\t2\t3\t4");
     lbMessages.Items.Add ("40\t50\t60\t70");
     lbMessages.Items.Add ("100\t200\t300\t400");
  }
```

However I'd have to ask why you would want to do this when better options like a ListView with proper header support exist. I suppose for a quick hack, or a minimal-change retrofit to an existing app, then it's kind of defensible, but a ListView would be better.

Comment: After a lot of time, I can note for FW 4.8 Winforms and VS2019 this solution still works for my listbox, AND for a font of my choice. If I could I'd put a green checker I would !